# Ubuntu not finishing installing after reboot from windows installer

Tags: installation, wubi, reboot, re-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my desktop from the windows installer. It installs but once it finishes and says to reboot, I reboot my computer, and it gives me this:

```
TRY(HD0,0): NTFS5: No wuildr 
TRY(HD0,1): NTFS5: No wuildr
TRY(HD0,2): NTFS5: No wuildr 
TRY(HD0,3): NTFS5: No Wuildr 
Try(fd0) :FAT32: no WUBILDR 
Cannot find GRLDR.
```

It had once installed but never actually loaded so I uninstalled and reinstalled it and this is what I get now:

```
it is a 64 bit windows 7 operating system
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that `it is a 64 bit windows 7 operating system` is really the full and exact text of the error message you got when you uninstalled and reinstalled. Do you have the complete and exact text of that message? Are you sure you have copied the other error messages exactly, as well? (Look carefully at spelling and capitalization.) If I knew it was miscopied and what it should say I wouldn't be asking. Even small differences in error messages can make it hard for people to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: There's a bug with a similar problem (except using Win8): https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/961707 I expect your problem is something similar - to do with NTFS rather than the OS. Try the workaround or add some diagnostics to the bug report. Thanks

Comment: no no I was just stating at the end what kind of system it is the error message is everything uptop

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact issue (64 bit Windows etc.). Found the fix here: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/2011/01/wubildr-wubildrmbr-and-grldr.html . In short, just copy all the wubildr files from the C:\ubuntu\winboot folder and paste into the root of your C drive. In my case, wubildr.mbr still existed in C; I decided not to overwrite. Everything else was missing. Reboot, and everything should be back to normal.